# Recursive call of a function does not get executed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think `d.push(f(b))` will never be executed.

Can you help me understand what this code is doing?`

```
function a(f, d) {
    if (d.length > 0) {
         var b = d.pop();
         a(f, d);
         d.push(f(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: `function incr(n){ return n + 1 }`  and try to pass to a `_ar =[[1,2,3,4],1,2,[3,4,5,6]]` `a(f, _ar)` then print `_ar`

Comment: Essentially does a `map` operation really badly.

Comment: shortly it change value of array by applying call back function on it

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through it in the browser's debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure why that edit was approved. I feel it misrepresents the posters intent. The poster had no idea what recursion was or what the function was doing. They weren't asking why the recursive call is not executed. Even what they asked about a specific line of code not being executed wasn't even the recursive call. Terrible edit.

Answer (score 4):

This is called recursion. A function that calls itself until some condition is met, in this case the condition is the array `a` is empty. Essentially this function takes a function `f` and an array `a` as parameters. If the array is not empty it removes the last index and calls itself again.

This continues to happen until the array is empty and then each recursive call returns and moves on to the next line which calls the function that was passed in initially passing it the array index value it popped and adds the returned result back to the array.

Below is an example of it working. Push is never executed until the array is empty but as long as the array had a length greater than 0 on the first call the push will eventually be executed. If the array was empty nothing happens.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3joe4yvz/

```
function a(f, d) {
    if (d.length > 0) {
        var b = d.pop();
        a(f, d);
        d.push(f(b));
    }
}

var someArray = [1,2,3];
function addOne (value) {
    return value + 1;
}
a(addOne,someArray);
alert(JSON.stringify(someArray));
```

Comment: @bmah no problem!! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this piece by piece.

```
function a(f, d) {
    if (d.length > 0) { // if the list is not empty
        var b = d.pop(); // remove the last element from the list
        a(f, d); // call this function recursively with the shortened list
        d.push(f(b)); // call f with the last item removed
                      // and add it to the list
    }
}
```

Let's assume you have a list with 3 elements in it: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Let's assume that `f` is a function which doubles a number: `function f(x) { return x * 2; }`.

Now we'll trace the call stack for `a(f, [1, 2, 3])`.

1. `a(f, [1, 2, 3])`

   1. Remove `3` from the list.
   2. Call `a(f, [1, 2])`.
2. `a(f, [1, 2])`

   1. Remove `2` from the list.
   2. Call `a(f, [1])`.
3. `a(f, [])`

   1. List is empty, do nothing.
4. `a(f, [1])` again

   1. `d` is now empty.
   2. Add `f(1)` to `d`: `d = [2]`
5. `a(f, [1, 2])` again

   1. `d` is now `[2]`
   2. Add `f(2)` to `d`: `d = [2, 4]`
6. `a(f, [1, 2, 3])` again

   1. `d` is now `[2, 4]`
   2. Add `f(3)` to `d`: `d = [2, 4, 6]`
7. Final result: `d = [2, 4, 6]`

In some ways, this is an implementation of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Great explanation, I got the gist of it, but I still feel at step 3. a(f,[]) the d.length > 0 will be false and so nothing in the subsequent { } should be executed then how come d.push.. is being executed??? Shouldnt it be outside the if statement for this to work the way you said.

Comment: @bmah Remember, this is a recursive function. After the function returns, it returns to the point that it was called. So it's not that `a(f, [])` is doing the changes, it's that all of the other calls to `a` are executing their `d.push(f(b))` when it returns to their turn. For recursion, there's a bit of a joke about learning it: in order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test this by pasting the code in the console and then running `a((b) => console.log(b), [1,2,3])` to see how it works. It loops over an array recursively (mutates the original array) and does something with each value.

Answer (score 0):

Your function (`function a`) gets a function (`f`) and an array (`d`) as input.

Lets say `d` is an array like `[element1, element2, element3]`.

your function pop `d` elements one by one (by calling itself recursively) until the final element (`element1` in our example).

After that it gives elements to function `f` and push them back to the array `d`

So the final result will be:
`[f(element1), f(element2), f(element3)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive implementation of a `map`, or `array_map`. It modifies the original array (as if it were passed by reference/pointer) by applying the first parameter (`f`, a function) to each of the elements in the list (`d`).

```
function a(f, d) {
    if (d.length > 0) {
        var b = d.pop();
        a(f, d);
        d.push(f(b));
    }
}

function my_array_map(my_func, my_list) {
    if (my_list.length > 0) {
        var first_element = my_list.pop();
        my_array_map(my_func, my_list);
        my_list.push( my_func(first_element) );
    }
}

var the_list = [2, 4, 6, 8];
var multiply = function(val) {
    return val * 2;
};
var divide = function(val) {
    return val / 2;
}


my_array_map(multiply, the_list);
console.log(the_list); // [4, 8, 12, 16]                                                                             
my_array_map(divide, the_list);
console.log(the_list); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
```